# Tensorflow: Inconsistent GPU recognition

Tags: tensorflow

I ran a check to see whether or not my Tensorflow installation is using my GPU using the example code from the Tensorflow instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu)

When I ran the code for the first time, I got this output:

```
$ python gpu-test.py
```

out:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA    library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GRID K520
major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.797
pciBusID 0000:00:03.0
Total memory: 3.94GiB
Free memory: 3.91GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GRID K520, pci bus id: 0000:00:03.0)
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GRID K520, pci bus id: 0000:00:03.0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:255] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GRID K520, pci bus id: 0000:00:03.0

MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:827] b: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:827] a: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
```

It's using the GPU, all good!

With this certainty in mind, I launch a Jupyter notebook with large CNN and train it, and it's super slow.

I'm confused and run `gpu-test.py` a second time. This time, even though nothing changed in the meantime, I get a different output:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:509] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:158] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: ip-172-31-19-90
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: ip-172-31-19-90
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: 375.39.0
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:363] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  367.57  Mon Oct  3 20:37:01 PDT 2016
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
"""
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: 367.57.0
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:303] kernel version 367.57.0 does not match DSO version 375.39.0 -- cannot find working devices in this configuration
Device mapping: no known devices.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:255] Device mapping:

MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:827] MatMul: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:827] b: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:827] a: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
```

I am completely confused right now.

The only two things that happened between me running the GPU test the first and the second time were (1) I unziped a file and (2) I ran said Jupyter notebook. **Nothing** was installed, updated, or in anyway changed about the system from my side.

Can anybody help?

How come this is happening all of a sudden when it didn't happen 5 minutes earlier:

```
kernel version 367.57.0 does not match DSO version 375.39.0
```

And how can I update the kernel version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out what happened: An automatic driver update running in the background as an unattended update tried to update the driver to version 375.39.0.

The GRID K520 GPUs on the AWS g2.2xlarge instances, however, are too old for this driver version.

The attempted automatic update leaves the system in an inconsistent state and breaks it all.

The only way for me was to launch a new AWS instance and kill the update process right after startup to keep the system intact. Very annoying issue :/.

If anyone happens to have the same problem:

- Launch a fresh AWS g2 instance
- SSH yourself in immediately
- Display running processes by typing `top` into the terminal
- Check if there's a busy process saying "unattended...." and if yes, copy its PID (process ID)
- Kill it with `kill -9 PID` before it can attempt to install the update

Answer (score 1):

This means you need to update your cuda driver to the latest version. Not sure where the inconsistency could be coming from.